# undefined method `model_name' for #<User:XXXXXXXX>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, mongoid

I have a dashboard containing 2 partials. One partial works fine and does what its suppose to (bill). The other partial is setup similar to bill but wont work(request). When I look at my log it shows that the tenant(user) is being queried, also, the 1st partial is queried but the 2nd partial doesn't query. when I went to my dashboard controller and changed the instance of the partial to (Request.new) it works but I can't seem to get it to work right thru the controller. I don't want to have the method in the model. I am using mongoid.

SO here is my render in the dashboard...

```
        <%= render partial: "request", locals: {request: @request} %>
```

In the partial I have...

```
    <%= form_for [:tenants, request] do |f| %>
```

And on the dashboard controller I have...

```
  def show
    @dashboard = current_tenant
    @bill = current_tenant.bill || current_tenant.build_bill
    @request = current_tenant.request || current_tenant.build_request
  end
```

(if I change @request = Request.new it works fine but I know that's not right)

The bill partial works and the dashboard finds the tenant but I keep getting

"undefined method `request' for #

Any idea of what I am missing? I compared the bill controller to the request controller and I cant find any differences. When I put the Model.new into the dashboard controller it works but I know this isn't right, its as if the app wont recognize the Request controller...

The error is saying it doesn't recognize "request" method.

Also here is my controller for request...

```
class Tenants::RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_tenant!

  def index
    @requests = Request.all
  end

  def show
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    if @request = current_tenant.create_request(authorization_params)
      redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, :notice => "#{request.manager_name} has been Authorized!"
    else
      redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, :error => "#{request.manager_name} has NOT been Authorized, please try again."
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if current_tenant.request.update_attributes(authorization_params)
      redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, :notice => "You have approved #{request.manager_name} to review your report"
    else
      redirect_to tenants_dashboard_path, :notice => "#{request.manager_name} is NOT allowed to review your report"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
    name = @request.name

    if @request.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{name}\" was successfully removed from your profile."
      redirect_to @dashboard
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting this managers access."
      render :show
    end
  end
```

Comment: Getting confused at which controller is which. Can you label your code snippets better? Are you saying that `current_tenant.request` is undefined? So request is not a method available for current_tenant ?

Comment: I will clarify with an edit

Comment: just fyi, your other controller isn't relevant as far as I can see. Your model of request would be more relevant

Comment: Yes, I know I was just making mention that this model and controller are somewhat similar and for some reason one works and the other doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like

`current_tenant.request` has an issue. That means that the method is not available. Assuming you're not trying to access the http `request` , then you have an issue with the request method.

So your issue is with how you defined the request method (maybe in your model). e.g. is it a class method or a instance method etc.

Without knowing your goal, that's the general answer I can give you. Creating a `Request.new` could be right depending on your goal, but if your goal is to call the request method, you must make it available to `current_tenant`

One controller shouldn't be calling your other controller as you have suggested...

Comment: No 1 controller isnt calling another. I just meant it is similar to the request model and it works yet the request one doesnt. The final goal is for this partial to allow the tenant/user to grant the manager/user access to a file. And I thought the Request.new should not go into the view, it should be able to be accessed by the controller

Comment: `Request.new`  shouldn't go in your view, but it can be in your controller

Comment: it can go in the dashboard controller? because thats where it makes the page work.

Comment: yes. i don't see why that would be an issue. it usually only goes in two places, the controller or the model. if you don't have a lot of operations with it, it  can sit happily on a controller

Comment: Thanks Clam! Thats what I needed to know

Comment: np. you can accept and close this question. happy coding